# Wordpress NAVIGATION Bar not visible

Tags: css, wordpress

on the site

the navigation bar is not visible

any CSS Problem ?

Comment: There are some files missing. you can inspect it in google chrome...

Comment: Is the nagivation bar supposed to be in the black backgrounded area?

Comment: background image of nav is not loading

Comment: the background image is unimportant.

Comment: It should be just above the navigation without wallpaper

Comment: something is wrong with the drop-down plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `wp-content/themes/immotech/style.css` line 184 :

```
#top #nav ul {
  display: none;
```

And there are a lot of errors on your site :

```
GET http://it.mediameans.de/themes/default/default.css 404 (Not Found) http://it.mediameans.de/:14
GET http://it.mediameans.de/nivo-slider.css 404 (Not Found) http://it.mediameans.de/:14
GET http://it.mediameans.de/js/cufon.js 404 (Not Found) http://it.mediameans.de/:14
GET http://it.mediameans.de/js/quicksand.font.js 404 (Not Found) http://it.mediameans.de/:14
GET http://it.mediameans.de/js/jquery.js 404 (Not Found) http://it.mediameans.de/:14
GET http://it.mediameans.de/js/custom.js 404 (Not Found) http://it.mediameans.de/:14
GET http://it.mediameans.de/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js 404 (Not Found) http://it.mediameans.de/:14
GET http://it.mediameans.de/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js 404 (Not Found) http://it.mediameans.de/:14
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function http://it.mediameans.de/:217
GET http://it.mediameans.de/wp-content/themes/immotech/images/skin2/border_vertical.png 404 (Not Found) http://it.mediameans.de/:105
```

Answer (score 1):

Open up your header.php file located in your theme folder

located this section..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/cufon.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/quicksand.font.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/custom.js'></script>
```

change it to

```
// if you want to use the default stylesheet, copy the file default.css from the default theme folder and paste it into your theme folder,
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/cufon.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/quicksand.font.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/custom.js'></script>
```

**MAKE SURE** the files are located in the correct folder within your theme folder it should load...

have a read through the documentation http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

M